# Simple correct implementation file in verbose syntax?

Tags: f#

**UPDATE**

The general question is: how to use verbose syntax of F# correctly? Verbose syntax is the syntax which is close to OCaml syntax, i.e. syntax with many commas etc.

**OLD TEXT**

I want to turn light syntax off in `F#` to have verbose syntax which is closer to `OCaml`.

I wrote the following code

```
#light "off"

let k=3.14;;
```

and got an error on let:

```
Unexpected keyword 'let' or 'use' in implementation file
```

What is correct implementation file structure without light syntax?

Comment: You don't actually need `#light` anymore - but it should still be fine

Comment: @John I guess you misunderstood me: I want to have light OFF to have syntax be closer to OCaml

Comment: I see the `light` thing now. typing your example into `fsi` works fine for me - perhaps you have some funny unicode characters somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have written this inside a `.fsi` file - which is an FSharp Interface definition file; it has nothing to do with `fsi.exe` (FSharp Interactive).

The message "Unexpected keyword 'let' or 'use' in implementation file" is a tell - interface definitions were expected. Simply use a `.fs` extension.

If you want reuse ML code, consider changing the file extension to `.ml`, and add a `#nowarn "62"` directive at the beginning to ignore the legacy warning.

```
#nowarn "62"
#light "off"

let div2 = 2;;

let f x = 
    let r = x % div2 in
      if r = 1 then 
        begin "Odd"  end 
      else 
        begin "Even" end
```

Comment: I want to use F# but with verbose syntax. How to do that?

Comment: @SuzanCioc a `.fs` file with `#light "off"` is the way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong but... why the two ;? Are you compiling it or running in fsi?